# How can I determine which OS image I am running?

Tags: raspbian, debian

I have been given a pre-installed SD card.  It boots fine, and I know it is running some version of Raspbian.  Can I determine exactly which release it is running?

Comment: A note to all answeres: Gnu/Linux may be the favourite OS. But the Rasperry Pi supports other OS like BSD, Plan 9, RISC OS too.

Comment: @ott--...and Windows 10 IOT.

Comment: @PaulFleming Win 10 IoT? Not really.  Not a real OS.  You can't do anything on it.  You can only run apps created separately (i.e. on a different device/platform) in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
uname -a
```

will give you the kernel version etc. There are some other parameters you could try as well - to see them:

```
man uname
```

Comment: The question was about the distro version, not the kernel version, so this answer is really not useful.

Comment: I can't help it if he chose to accept the wrong answer. Perhaps it gave him what he needed.

Comment: **uname -a** displays `Linux raspberrypi 4.4.32-v7+ #924 SMP Tue Nov 15 18:11:28 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`.  However, I need to know if the Pi is running Debian 7 or Debian 8.

Comment: Need to know Jessie vs Stretch...

Comment: See correct answer, below: `cat /etc/os-release`, thanks to @w5m

Answer (score 315):

Open `Terminal` and type:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

This results in the following output on my Raspberry Pi 2...

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: This answer clearly displayed what version of Raspbian I am running, unlike the chosen answer.

Comment: This worked on *Stretch* on a Pi 2 too.  When I ran it tonight on a Virtualbox VM running the latest Raspbian Desktop *Stretch* (the PC version) it gives **Debian** for `PRETTY_NAME`, `ID` and the `*URL` values :-( . I'm unsure, seems like an oversight by Raspbian maintainers to me.

Comment: this should be the correct answer thank you for this post UPVOTE!

Comment: definitely the right answer

Answer (score 26):

Do not look at `uname -a`. That just shows kernel version. To find the distribution version, run:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-release
lsb_release -a
```

My RPi shows:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:    7.8
Codename:   wheezy
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. Install another app just to give what you can get for free with `cat /etc/os-release` or `cat /etc/*-release` is not good

Comment: It is *an* answer and is perfectly valid for the Raspbian distro which is derived from Debian which aims for compliance with the [Linux Standards Base](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/LSB).

Comment: It may be the right answer but not the most useful one.

Answer (score 23):

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen/releases lists releases of Raspbian since 2016-05-10.

To find your Raspbian distribution image release date (not the /etc/os-release information such as VERSION="8 (jessie)") on a running system:

```
$ cat /etc/rpi-issue
Raspberry Pi reference 2016-05-10
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, c32099002b4c44243e87d8cc90303237eb5ce06a, stage4
```

Note if you did 'apt-get {dist-,}upgrade' or rpi-update, you will have updated some files since you first installed that distribution image.

[The original poster asked back in 2013, before the github URL existed, but this answer may help some users in 2016.]

Update: Instead of actually running Raspbian on that mysterious Raspbian SD card, you could also mount the SD card in a Linux or Windows desktop SD reader to read the /issue.txt file directly.  /issue.txt exists in the root directory of the SD card's FAT16 partition.  From Ubuntu 16.04.1, I see the following on a second SD card I have:

```
Raspberry Pi reference 2016-09-23
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, 62406bad92ed23728f46711b3539c04c37dfb62c, stage4
```

Comment: This file is present even on the *Raspbian Desktop* PC ISO image, and since it's generated by `pi-gen` it seems it's automatically updated, unlike `/etc/os-release` which it appears is manually edited, and was overlooked on the latest PC image of Raspbian.

Comment: +1 because this gives the exact release - there are several different releases of e.g. Jessie

Answer (score 2):

Almost what Cerin wrote. Just `lsb_release -a` and you don't need to install the LSB module to see the raspbian description

Comment: When I try this I get: `-bash: lsb_release: command not found` but this goes away when I install the lsb-release package.

Answer (score 1):

The following script is one I use to collect relevant details. (It is called **about**)

You can run this or the individual commands

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ -e /etc/rpi-issue ]; then
 echo "- Original Installation"
 cat /etc/rpi-issue
fi
if [ -e /usr/bin/lsb_release ]; then
 echo "- Current OS"
 lsb_release -irdc
fi
echo "- Kernel"
uname -r
echo "- Model"
cat /proc/device-tree/model && echo
echo "- hostname"
hostname
echo "- Firmware"
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
```

The output on my Pi3A+ shows

```
- Original Installation
Raspberry Pi reference 2018-11-13
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, 7e0c786c641ba15990b5662f092c106beed40c9f, stage4
- Current OS
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:    9.6
Codename:   stretch
- Kernel
4.14.79-v7+
- Model
Raspberry Pi 3 Model A Plus Rev 1.0
- hostname
MilliwaysPi3A
- Firmware
Nov  4 2018 16:31:07 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version ed5baf9520a3c4ca82ba38594b898f0c0446da66 (clean) (release)
Filesystem created:       Tue Jan  1 12:09:51 2019
```

It should produce a meaningful output on most Linux distributions, e.g. Ubuntu MATE

```
- Current OS
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
- Kernel
4.4.38-v7+
- Model
Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1
- hostname
PiUbuntu
- Firmware
Dec  9 2016 15:11:26 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 2e557d8dac70add28597c3b449cb52c34588d818 (clean) (release)
```

Comment: Worked on RPi Compute Module 3 Plus Rev 1.0.
If you got `/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter) to replace Windows style line endings with Unix style.

Answer (score -1):

open terminal and type

> cat /proc/version

Comment: That will only show kernel version, not distribution version.