# Unable to install dialog package

Tags: apt, raspbian-wheezy, source.list

I'm using wheezy on my raspi and wanted to install `dialog`.

```
sudo apt-get install dialog
E: Package 'dialog' has no installation candidate
```

So I look up the source

```
Package: dialog
Versions:
1.1-20120215-2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages
```

my source.list looks like that

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

After `apt-get update` I have the same problem.

What source do I need to add?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

looks like the default live cd needs a repo update

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Answer (score 0):

[Confirm](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6974/how-can-i-determine-which-os-image-i-am-running) you are actually on Wheezy by running 
`cat /etc/os-release` which will probably print something like

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

there are threads over here https://askubuntu.com/a/14693/590737 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1704342 which are related to ubuntu but should pretty much apply here as well

Consider using Raspbian/Jessie if you can and see if it works

last resort, directly install the deb from here but this might break something so consider having a backup of the SD card in case it does

http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dialog/