# What Chromium version does RaspberryPi 3.0 use?

Tags: pi-3

What version of Raspberry Pi 3.0 use? it just says `chromium` in the browser.

Comment: The version of the Pi isn't the important bit here; it's the version of Raspbian you're using that matters. You should [edit] to state that in your question — see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/6974/58316 to determine your OS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, if you're on a desktop or full screen browser, would be to enter either of the following in the address bar of the browser;

```
about:
```

or...

```
chrome://version
```

Answer (score 1):

when you type "chromium --version" in the terminal, it should output the version number you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that the version of Chromium is not dependent on the hardware (Raspberry pi 3.0) but rather on the image or distribution of linux, usually Rasperian. The current versions of Raspian (nicknamed 'stretch') ship with Chromium browser 60.0. To see the exact version, from a command line 'chromium-browser --version'. To upgrade to the latest: 'sudo apt-get install chromium-browser'.